# Is it possible to create a dropdown / select field using Amplify Studio UI & Figma?

Tags: forms, aws-amplify, figma

I'm trying to use AWS Amplify Studios's UI Library with Figma to create a dropdown component.

I've followed the AWS docs [Figma to Code](https://docs.amplify.aws/console/uibuilder/figmatocode/) page and set up the [AWS Amplify UI Kit](https://www.figma.com/community/file/1047600760128127424). I've successfully got simple text elements updating from the Amplify database. The UI Kit also contains components with dropdowns, but I can't find any information anywhere as to how to design this in Figma. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Studio doesn't currently support importing select lists due to some of the ambiguity in how it would handle importing the options. There is a backlog item to allow them to be imported and configured with options after the fact within Studio. We don't have a timeline for when that would be released though.